# reload page after removing row from sql

Tags: php

Been hustling with this for a while but cant still get the page to reload after deleted a row.

The row removing is working fine, but it only appears after I reload the page. 
Been moving around some of the code to get it read when pressing submit but no luck.
Any Ideas ?

```
 <?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
mysql_select_db("booking") or die(mysql_error()) ;

$resultselect = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test_mysql ") or die(mysql_error()); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 

    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
        <title>row delete</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" /> 
    </head> 

    <body>
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['done'])){
    $done = implode(',', $_POST['done']);
    $deletequery = "DELETE FROM test_mysql WHERE id IN ($done)";
    $resultdelete = mysql_query($deletequery) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    ?>

    <form method="post" action="">
    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultselect)){?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="done[]" 
    id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"
    value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
    <label for="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
    <?php echo $row['name'] . ' ' . $row['lastname']. ' '.$row['email']; ?>
    </label>
    <br />
    <?php } ?>
    <input type ="submit" value ="submit">
    </form>
    <?php 

    if($resultdelete) {
        echo 'Item(s) deleted from list.';
    }
    ?>

    <pre>
    <?php print_r($_POST) ?>
     </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are saying.  So, when you click 'submit' and it removes the rows you checked, the rows you deleted are still showing up on the page?

Comment: Exactly. The row are still showing up until I reload the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming since the code you have provided is a snippet of your application code that `$resultselect` is set someplace before this part gets executed.

The important part here is the order of your MySQL queries.  If you are `SELECT`ing rows *before* you `DELETE` rows, then you will still see deleted rows when you run `mysql_fetch_array()`

Move the `SELECT` query after the `DELETE` query and all should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are getting your resultset for $row in a section of code prior to the delete statement. If you place your $deletequery code at the top of the page, you can delete the appropriate records of data, then get a new resultset and THEN display them to the user.

Whatever query feeds your loop

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultselect))
{
....
}
```

needs to run AFTER the

```
$resultdelete = mysql_query($deletequery) or die(mysql_error());
```

statement.

Editing for full code to run:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
    mysql_select_db("booking") or die(mysql_error()) ;

    if(isset($_POST['done']))
    {
        $done = implode(',', $_POST['done']);
        $deletequery = "DELETE FROM test_mysql WHERE id IN ($done)";
        $resultdelete = mysql_query($deletequery) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    $resultselect = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test_mysql ") or die(mysql_error()); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 

    <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
    <title>row delete</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" /> 
    </head> 

    <body>
    <form method="post" action="">
    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultselect)){?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="done[]" 
    id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"
    value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
    <label for="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
    <?php echo $row['name'] . ' ' . $row['lastname']. ' '.$row['email']; ?>
    </label>
    <br />
    <?php } ?>
    <input type ="submit" value ="submit">
    </form>
    <?php 

    if($resultdelete) {
    echo 'Item(s) deleted from list.';
    }
    ?>

    <pre>
    <?php print_r($_POST) ?>
     </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In that case, could you please post your entire code so that I can have a look?